# Can Avro Return References to Objects Instead of Objects

Tags: java, performance, apache-kafka, avro

I'm using Avro to deserialize Kafka messages into Java objects.  Many of the objects created are identical to previous objects.  Can Avro return references to exsiting objects instead of creating new objects?

Comment: Can you please show an example of what you're expecting? You could place an offset marker in your Avro data for Kafka to do referential lookups, but this does not seem Avro specific